# How to paste Excel data into Outlook as an image using VBA?

Tags: image, vba, excel, outlook

I have an Excel sheet with data in `a1:q38` that I need to paste into the BODY of an outlook email. Any idea how to do this while not saving the image as a jpg or png?

Comment: Go to Excel. Select your data. CTRL + C. Go to Outlook. ALT then H then V then S then select "Paste as Picture".

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon unless you are suggesting using "sendkeys", OP specifically stated they are looking for a VBA solution.

Comment: Do you actually want this to be a VBA solution? If so, please show your attempt at a VBA solution thus far. However given the trivial nature of the manual solution, I assume this will be sufficient. @Eddy - you will notice that I offered this as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, **you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body**.

For example, you can use the Copy method of the `Range` class from the Excel object model and then use the [Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845105(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Range class from the Word object model to paste the copied data in Excel.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.